# Update statement throwing error type " " does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have this simple update statement which is throwing the error below and I can't figure out why.

```
UPDATE myschema.webhooks SET app_id = NULL WHERE app_id = 'testing';
```

```
ERROR:  type " " does not exist
LINE 1: ... myschema.webhooks SET app_id = NULL WHERE app_id = 'testing...
```

Comment: The update statement looks fine to me. I suppose the error is somewhere else.

Comment: Seems there was some weird character between `=` and `'testing'`..

Comment: @Catfish seems to be right, look at this similar situation: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAADeyWiRqpYqZn1cushfefs9rQahUbqHKNbffU44o5%3DegLDf2Q%40mail.gmail.com

Comment: Are there triggers on the table?

Comment: Nope. There's some weird whitespace issues when writing as a migration in VScode. Migration was failing and copying this directly to postico was also failing until I removed that space and then re-added it in postico.